# Insert angular component with plain html into Category Page only without CMS Components

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

Insert angular component with plain html into Category Page only without CMS Components.

Is it possible?

The main reason why I want to add static html on Spartacus/Angular side for a specific page like Category Page is that our customer want to be independent of Hybris CMS and as a result to have separate deployment process which not depends of Hybris CMS.

I thought that I can create, e.g separate route with custom angular component but if I want to do this, manual service calls are necessary to load products for provided category in route param (edited) but I want to save logic of loading products data but I don't want to use CMS.

Comment: Thread in Slack: https://spartacus-storefront.slack.com/archives/CD16V16FR/p1583251650118500

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a  capability to add static CMS Components in JavaScript without having the components represented server-side.   See defaultCmsContentConfig/defaultHeaderConfig for examples.

If the main requirement is: don't depend on calls to the backend for CMS structures … then the static CMS configuration approach could also be used.  If you are using that approach entirely, then it is quite powerful. (It has limitations where you are mixing static vs backend CMS content, so I don’t think you can combine both into a single content slot).  For the mobile views, the defaultCmsContentConfig/defaultHeaderConfig pieces add new content slots & put components into those content slots.

You could go a lot further if you wanted to  … to the extent of fully configuring the ‘CMS’ data in your JS.  If you look at the CmsPageConfig type it even includes an ignoreBackend property. If you created a series of config classes to setup your page structures in JS you could then disregard management of CMS items in the Commerce backend, but still re-use the functionality of those CMS components